# zxingの縦画面対応

Tags: java, android, android-layout

zxingを使用してバーコードを読み取るアプリを作成しております。
疑問に思ったことなのですが、カメラ起動すると画面が縦から横になってしまいます。

縦画面で起動する方法ってあるのでしょうか。

開発環境
AndroidStudio 1.3.1
zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3
zxing:core:3.2.0

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Cameraクラスを使っているならsetDisplayOrientationで出来ます。

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)

Answer (score 0):

今更ですが、回答です。

zxing-android-embedded では、縦画面にするためには、CaptureActivityを継承した空のActivityを作成し、manifestにてorientationを指定する方法しかなかったと思います。

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#changing-the-orientation

私の用途ではもう少し色々やりたかったので、これを使うのをやめ、独自Viewを実装している別のライブラリを使用しました。けっこう使い勝手がよかったので、ぜひ検討してみてください。

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner